# Excel: "if result is 0, insert something else" without IF

Tags: excel

All I can find on the internet is simple examples where people don't consider that "A1" could be something really huge:

```
=IF(A1=0;"my_replacement";A1)
```

I do not want to write A1 twice (in the comparison and in the else branch), isn't there something like "check the result of this super long expression. if it is 0, put something else instead"? Something like `IFERROR` but not for an error ... ?

Comment: Will `A1` be a numerical value?

Comment: In situations like this, I always used a second column. Calculate the value, then refer to it in a second column with the check for 0.

Comment: A1 is a vlookup inside an iferror which will always return a string. Okay Greg, will do that ... I thought there must be a solution that doesn't involve an interim result column =/ thank you!

Comment: There are ways of doing it, but they always involve repeating the expression. There is no "IFZERO" function.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function for this:

In VBA:

```
Function IsZero(r As Range, Replacement As String)
  If r.Value <> 0 Then
    IsZero = r.Value
  Else:
    IsZero = Replacement
  End If
End Function
```

In Excel, you can have following examples:

[image]

Which is based on the formula:

```
=IsZero(A1;"test")
```